# Getting 'ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis' when I copy code from Oracle SQL Dev into Tableau even though there are no parentheses in the code

Tags: sql, oracle, tableau-api

As stated in the title, I'm getting an error when I copy the below code into Tableau - 'ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis'. Extremely weird since there are no parentheses at all in my code, which is simply pulling out a subset of columns and rows from a large table. The code works fine in Oracle SQL Developer... any ideas?

```
SELECT f.gl_date_revenue, f.gl_date_cogs, f.bill_to_customer_id, f.ship_to_customer_id, f.inventory_item_id, f.sob_currency_code, f.sob_extended_amount, f.usd_extended_amount, f.units, f.country_name, f.territory
FROM my_schema.my_table f
WHERE f.territory = 'Nordic';
```

Comment: Try removing the semi-colon

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Debug your code:

1. Remove anything unnecessary.

   In this case, you can remove the table alias and the trailing semi-colon:

   ```sql
   SELECT gl_date_revenue, gl_date_cogs, bill_to_customer_id, ship_to_customer_id, inventory_item_id, sob_currency_code, sob_extended_amount, usd_extended_amount, units, country_name, territory
   FROM my_schema.my_table
   WHERE territory = 'Nordic'
   ```
2. Remove necessary code until your code works.

   - Remove the `WHERE` clause, does it work?
   - Remove columns until it works.
   - Put columns back one-by-one until you find the column that breaks it.
   - Read the tableau documentation to see if that column name has any special meaning.

Comment: Turns out removing the semi-colon did the trick! Thanks a lot - I'm a beginner so your other comments will be v useful as well going forward